# Spark-shell vs Spark-submit adding jar to classpath issue

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I'm able to run `CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION testFunc using jar 'myJar.jar'` query in **hiveContext** via `spark-shell --jars myJar.jar -i some_script.scala`, but I'm not able to run such command via `spark-submit --class com.my.DriverClass --jars myJar.jar target.jar`.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using local file system, the Jar must be in the same location on all nodes.

So you have 2 options:

- place jar on all nodes in the same directory, for example in /home/spark/my.jar and then use this directory in --jars option.
- use distributed file system like HDFS

Comment: should I use full path in --jars or in ADD JAR also? I mean full hdfs path